# difference between sessionfactory.openSession() and sessionfactory.openStatelessSession()?

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to know the conceptual difference between the above mentioned two methods of the hibernates sessionfactory class if poosible with simple example.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The former opens a normal (stateful) session, while the latter (probably not surprisingly) a *stateless session*.

According to [the Javadoc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/org/hibernate/StatelessSession.html), a stateless session is:

> A command-oriented API for performing bulk operations against a database.
>
> A stateless session does not implement a first-level cache nor interact with any second-level cache, nor does it implement transactional write-behind or automatic dirty checking, nor do operations cascade to associated instances. Collections are ignored by a stateless session. Operations performed via a stateless session bypass Hibernate's event model and interceptors. Stateless sessions are vulnerable to data aliasing effects, due to the lack of a first-level cache.
>
> For certain kinds of transactions, a stateless session may perform slightly faster than a stateful session.

Comment: How would you manage context in case of stateless session. I want to use getCurrentStatelessSession.