# Prevent hibernate from flushing on read only operations

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I have a heavy operation, which is read only. This is all mapped by hibernate, in a spring boot application.
Hibernate spends 6seconds flushing my entities, when there is no mutation of any sort. This is simply a get operation.

I am trying to stop hibernate from spending that 6 second, flushing redundantly.

I put hibernate flush mode to MANUAL/NEVER. But it didn't make any difference.

The property is set correctly, but hibernate stats still show the flushing, count, and the time spent.

Comment: Have you considered marking the entities as `@Immutable` to see if that improves performance for you if they truly are _read-only_ or are you merely trying to prevent the flush before a read-only query?

Comment: That is an idea. But a bit of work, as the entities are not really immutable. Only in case of this flow, they don't change.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to do it. You may try:
`org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional` annotation set to read-only:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
```

Which in case of Hibernate, it sets the JDBC transaction into a read-only mode and FlushMode.NEVER.
Here details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1712328/5810648

Also, it is possible to disable dirty-check calling `setReadOnly(true)` on Hibernate query or call `setHint("org.hibernate.readOnly", true)` on JPA query. According to doc :

> Hibernate will never dirty-check them or make changes persistent ( eg.
>   new Boolean(true) ), default to false

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/entitymanager/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#d0e1215

Another way is to use stateless session for that heavy operation. Here is details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5497077/5810648

Comment: I tried read only transactions, they didn't do the job somehow. I also tried setting flush mode to false manually. That also didn't cut it. I guess the problem is spring boot is creating the entity manager JPA way, and it somehow bypasses these settings. I am not sure though.

Comment: I confirm that putting `@Transactional(readOnly=true)` calls `setHibernateFlushMode(MANUAL)` (not NEVER) on the Hibernate session. Verified by a `@SpringBootTest` annotated on the test method, `TransactionSynchronizationManager.isCurrentTransactionReadOnly()` was true as expected, and `entityManager.unwrap(Session.class).getHibernateFlushMode()` returned MANUAL. This was with spring-tx:5.0.8 and hibernate-core:5.2.17.FINAL

Comment: But note, when you perform an *explicit* `saveAndFlush(entity)`, the behaviour may be unexpected. Within `@Transactional(readOnly=true)`, the entity will not be persisted, and there will be no exception. Within `@Transactional(readOnly=true, propagation=SUPPORTS)`, again no exception, but the entity *will* be persisted! (This is because the operation executes non-transactionally.)